# parse json content of for key before use in angular 6 template

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I'm using `Angular 6`.

I have an array object in the component file.

```
items: Array<ItemData>;
```

**ItemData** interface has following content

```
export interface FavouriteProductData {
  id: number;
  type: string;
  content: string;
}
```

and **content** contains data in json_encoded format

```
'{"name":"Jonathan Suh","gender":"male"}';
```

In the template, I'm looping over `items` and want to print `name` field of the content.

```
<tr *ngFor="let i in items; id = index;">
  <td> {{ i.type }} </td>
  <td> {{ i.content.name }} </td>
</tr>
```

But since `content` is json_encoded. I'm not able to print its contents in the template.

**How can I parse JSON content in the template and save parsed content in a new variable?**

I tried with creating a method in the component

```
jsonDecode(item) {
  return JSON.parse(item.content);
}
```

and use in the template like

```
<tr *ngFor="let i in items; id = index; p = jsonDecode(i)">
  <td> {{ i.type }} </td>
  <td> {{ p.name }} </td>
</tr>
```

But this is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first approach working fine here [sample in Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pnzzux)

I have done slight changes in array varable declaration.

Component:

```
items : any =[];
name = 'Angular';
constructor(){
   this.items = [{id :'1', type :'spec' , content : '{"name":"Jonathan Suh","gender":"male"}'}];
}

extractNameFromJson(obj){
  obj = JSON.parse(obj);
  return obj.name;
}
```

HTML:

```
<tr *ngFor="let i of items;">
   <td> {{ i.type }} </td> 
   <td> {{ extractNameFromJson(i.content) }} </td>
</tr>
```

Its working as expected try this.

Comment: I'm following the same approach as of yours.

Comment: @Raja Mohamed Excellent it worked saved lot of time .. Thanks

Comment: this is a bad practice for the performance; is better you use a pipe for this ...